# How to exclude application.properties from RPM build using Spring Boot and Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

My spring boot application gets packaged as rpm file using **rpm-maven-plugin**. My goal is to exclude *application.properties* from rpm.

rpm-maven-plugin configs

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-rpm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>rpm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>rpm</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <group>demo-app</group>
        <mappings>
            <mapping>
                <directory>/var/demoapp/bin</directory>
                <filemode>755</filemode>
                <username>test</username>
                <groupname>test</groupname>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <location>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</location>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </mapping>
            <mapping>
                <directory>/var/demoapp/conf</directory>
                <filemode>755</filemode>
                <username>test</username>
                <groupname>test</groupname>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <location>src/main/resources/</location>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </mapping>
        </mappings>
        <preinstallScriptlet>
            <scriptFile>src/main/resources/rpm/preinstall.sh</scriptFile>
        </preinstallScriptlet>
        <postinstallScriptlet>
            <scriptFile>src/main/resources/rpm/postinstall.sh</scriptFile>
        </postinstallScriptlet>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Project Folder structure - src/main/resources/application.properties

Folder structure inside rpm file

Parent folder - /var/demoapp

/bin - contains jar files

/conf - This folder contains application.properties file. This is to be removed

Can anyone guide on this?

Comment: You have configured the `conf` directory to contain the content of `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Yes, as per this => 


<mapping>
                <directory>/var/demoapp/conf</directory>
                <filemode>755</filemode>
                <username>test</username>
                <groupname>test</groupname>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <location>src/main/resources/</location>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </mapping>

Comment: I know that you have configured it because I see what you have configured in the pom (rpm configuration)..so what is your question?

Comment: Under src/main/resources I have so many other files including application.properties file. I want to exclude only application.properties so that it will not be present in the conf folder.

Comment: I hope my question is clear now?

Comment: Do not make a `conf` directory in your rpm because the `src/main` part is anyway packaged into the resulting jar (spring boot application). Or remove the file from `src/main/resources`..

Comment: src/main/resources folder has few yml files which I need under conf folder of rpm. So that I am checking if there a way to exclude only application properties from being packaged into rpm

Comment: First why need them in the rpm directory conf because they are already packaged into the resulting jar file. If you want to exclude them you have to separate building of the rpm and the application into separate modules...

Comment: Yes, they are already packaged into a jar but customer needs rpm file as a deliverable and they want to exclude application.properties in it

Comment: I have tried out adding excludes but didn't work 

<mapping>
                <directory>/var/demoapp/conf</directory>
                <filemode>755</filemode>
                <username>test</username>
                <groupname>test</groupname>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <location>src/main/resources/</location><excludes>
          <exclude>src/main/resources/application.properties</exclude>
         </excludes>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </mapping>

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade to most recent version of the rpm-maven-plugin https://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/source-params.html#excludes

Answer (score 0):

After modifying exclude path it worked

```
             <mapping>
                <directory>/var/demoapp/conf</directory>
                <filemode>755</filemode>
                <username>test</username>
                <groupname>test</groupname>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <location>src/main/resources/</location>
                        <excludes>
                         <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </mapping>
```

Here application.properties is present in src/main/resources/application.properties